# Linq: Nullable Object must have Value

Tags: linq

My query is as follows:

```
int ID = db.Q_Table.Find(item.PassedInID).ID;
```

I already found a solution for my issue, however i am wondering why i must write it like so

1.

```
Nullable(int) ID = db.Q_Table.Find(item.PassedInID).ID;
```

2.

```
db.Q_Table.Where(w => w.PassedInID== item.PassedInID).Select(s => s.ID ).SingleOrDefault();
```

It wouldn't let me put int int he < in the above code -.-...

I am curious why i have to code it to a nullable int? I really didn't want to code it like 2nd solution because its more code :). Yes i have made sure there are values in the database and from the below image you can see my database doesn't accept nulls.

Thanks for any answers

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `int` and `Nullable<int>` or `int?`, you can't directly assign a `Nullable<int>` to `int` ([`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), Consider:

```
int? x = 123;
int y = x; //This would be an error
```

But you can use [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
int? x = 123;
int y = x ?? 0;
```

Now for your case, your `ID` seems to be a mapped to column in database which allows `null`. That will map to C# `Nullable<int>`, if you want to assign the result to an `int` you can do:

```
int ID = db.Q_Table.Find(item.PassedInID).ID ?? 0;
```

That will give your variable the value of `ID` or `0` if it is null.

Comment: Edited above, database does not accept nullable values.. sorry for not saying that earlier.

Comment: What is the type of `ID` on the entity in `Q_Table`?

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle, how did you create the mapping ? did you write your own class *(Code-First)* or did you generate it through VS ?

Answer (score 1):

`ID` is not an `int` but rather a `Nullable<int>` (or short form `int?`).

This is typically the case when the underlying database column is nullable.

There is also no `<` operator defined on an `int?`. If you want to do that, you have to check for the presence of a value first:

```
db.Q_Table.Where(w => w.PassedInID.HasValue && w.PassedInID.Value == item.PassedInID)
  .Select(s => s.ID ).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Edited above, database does not accept nullable values.. sorry for not saying that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

that's probably because `db.Q_Table.Find` returns a nullible int.

you can probably also do the following if you wanted to

```
int? ID = db.Q_Table.Find(item.PassedInID).ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like the following, it is a little less code:

```
int? t;

int ID = (t = db.Q_Table.Find(item.PassedInID).ID) == null ? -1 : t;
```

Of course, now you will have to handle -1 ID as a special case later in your code.  I expect you just want a nullable int.